# Add to Campaign Button missing on campaign influence related list

Tags: campaign-influence

I have added campaign influence related list to opportunity, here is the screenshot of the list

[image: Campaign Influence screenshot]

I have created relevant permission set with CRM User assignment but still i am not able to see "Add to Campaign" button when i click on drop down

I also tried unchecking locked option is model attribution but it is leading to all campaigns associated in campaign influence disappering, therefore i checked this option once again

I am not sure what it the issue, kindly help on this!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this issue, I tried to add a Custom Model but it removes the existing Camapign influenece record from the Opportunity. Can you please share your approach on resolving this issue

Comment: I have the same problem. have logged a case with Salesforce

Comment: Salesforce were no help. Told me to unlock it. of course there's no way to unlock it. Created a new unlocked model and set that as default. will have to try to reload the Campaign Influence with the new default. Not even sure if that will work

Answer (score 2):

Set your custom campaign model as the default model. This will unlock the Create Action.